# Problems with tinyMCE and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I`m trying to get tinyMCE editor content, however

tinyMCE.get('ExVal')

always returns nothing.

`<textarea id="ExVal" name="ExVal" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 400px; height:380px;" 
runat="server"><%= Model.Text %></textarea>`

Comment: Tried the same on clean sample project, however result is the same :(

Answer (score 1):

From the official [documentation](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent):

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});
```

// Get content of a specific editor:

```
tinyMCE.get('content id').getContent();
```

Comment: First way worked, however I cannot find, why the second approach is not working.

Comment: This: tinyMCE.get('ExVal') will return an Editor instance, not the actual content of the editor.

Comment: +1 thats the way to go, the second approach will only work if your editor instance has id 'content id'